# How to Intercept XMLHttpRequest and change request URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

My front send requests to the back server. How can I intercept this request, and redirect to another back? How can I change back's URL?

```
  const intercept = (urlmatch, callback) => {
  let send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
    this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
      if (this.responseURL.includes(urlmatch) && this.readyState === 4) {
        callback(this);
      }
    }, false);
    send.apply(this, arguments);
  };
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the purpose? If it's possible that you may need another backend then urls should preferably constructed with base url constant that could be changed. Why are you trying to patch `send `and not `open`?

Comment: Do you mean without changing the code in frontend?

Comment: @estus I need to create an intercpetor, which will redirect all frontend requests from one backend to another

Comment: @AkshayMilmile Almost, just adding new function

Comment: this seems like front-end code, are you trying to intercept at the GUI level?

Comment: Don't do this, unless you need to hack existing app and have no permission to modify original code. If you need to augment the functionality of a built-in, It's always preferable to create a wrapper over it.

Comment: @estus Ok, I have another idea... Can I create another request, inside this interceptor, to send catched data to the second server?

Comment: Then you asked about wrong thing. Just changing backend URL is simpler. At this point this becomes messy because you need to create a unpatched copy of XMLHttpRequest or differentiate between requests to not create recursive request. You may have XY problem. If you use raw XHR then replace all occurrences of `new XMLHttpRequest()` with custom class.

Comment: @estus I can't just change backend URL. I need to send data at first to the second  backend and then to the first backend :(

Comment: I'm not sure how this should work then. A response from which server should be returned? Is it a request or a *response* from first server that you want to send to second server? Again, a cleaner way is to not patch XMLHttpRequest but to do this at higher level. I'd suggest to reask the question with relevant details, i.e. how XMLHttpRequest  is used in your app. If you don't use XMLHttpRequest directly but through some library, then it's this library that needs to be extended.

Answer (score 7):

This can be easily achieved by patching `XMLHttpRequest` `open`:

```
const intercept = (urlmatch, newurl) => {
  const open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, ...rest) {
    url = url.replace(urlmatch, newurl);
    return open.call(this, method, url, ...rest);
  };
}

intercept('http:/example.com/', 'http:/my-example.com/');
```

**Modifying globals for local needs is a bad practice that may lead to unforseen consequences.**

Unless the goal is to tamper somebody else's application (for instance, with user script), a cleaner way is to modify the application to make it possible to change base url, e.g. from

```
makeRequest('http:/example.com/api/...')
```

to

```
makeRequest(BASE_API_URL + '...')
```

Where `BASE_API_URL` is application constant that can be changed on application initialization, with environment variables, globals, dependency injection, etc.

If an application uses some kind of a wrapper instead of `XMLHttpRequest` directly, base URL functionality may be implemented in a wrapper.